# ¿Por qué se produce este error al actualizar un dato de formulario en Access (Visual Basic)?

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Access 2003. Cuando intento actualizar el resultado de una subvención, mediante este método:

```
Public Function CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023(sAno As String, sTH As String, sOca As String, sCen As Integer, sExp As String, ByVal valorSubvencioGastosCerti As Currency, ByVal valorSubvencionGastosCondiciones As Currency) As Integer

On Error GoTo err_CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023

Dim stsql As String

Dim totalSubvencionUnicaCerti As Double
totalSubvencionUnicaCerti = CDbl(Round(valorSubvencioGastosCerti + valorSubvencionGastosCondiciones, 2))

'Actualizamos la tabla correspondiente para poder trabajar con su valor
     stsql = "UPDATE  ADMINSTJA.TBJAESTTIT TABLADATOS SET "
    stsql = stsql + " TABLADATOS.TITPRIMAUNICACERTI =" & CvtSql(totalSubvencionUnicaCerti)
    stsql = stsql + " WHERE TABLADATOS.ESTANO='" & sAno & "'"
    stsql = stsql + " AND TABLADATOS.THCOD='" & sTH & "'"
    stsql = stsql + " AND TABLADATOS.OCACOD='" & sOca & "'"
    stsql = stsql + " AND TABLADATOS.CENCOD=" & sCen
    stsql = stsql + " AND TABLADATOS.EXPCOD='" & sExp & "'"
    GBDBAct.Execute stsql, dbFailOnError
    CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023 = 1
    Forms!FRCertificaJA.Refresh
err_CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023:
    MsgBox "Error al calcular la subvención certificada total. "
    MsgBox stsql
    CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023 = 0
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

No es más que sumar los importes obtenidos en dos apartados y actualizar el campo correspondiente. Los valores se obtienen sin problemas y la sentencia de actualización funciona bien en el gestor de base de datos. ¿Se puede saber el motivo o la razón de que no se ejecute desde Access esta función?

La sentencia sql que se obtiene es:

```
UPDATE  ADMINSTJA.TBJAESTTIT TABLADATOS SET  TABLADATOS.TITPRIMAUNICACERTI =10000 WHERE TABLADATOS.ESTANO='2022' AND TABLADATOS.THCOD='20' AND TABLADATOS.OCACOD='04' AND TABLADATOS.CENCOD=4 AND TABLADATOS.EXPCOD='0006'
```

No tiene ningún fallo de sintaxis. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Me acabo de dar cuenta que se me había olvidado añadir `exit function` si todo iba bien. Como el código se lee de arriba a abajo y de izquierda a derecha, seguía ejecutándose, por lo que siempre marcaba error.

La solución contiene sólo una línea de código extra:

```
Public Function CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023(sAno As String, sTH As String, sOca As String, sCen As Integer, sExp As String, ByVal valorSubvencioGastosCerti As Currency, ByVal valorSubvencionGastosCondiciones As Currency) As Integer

'On Error GoTo err_CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023

Dim stsql As String

Dim totalSubvencionUnicaCerti As Double
totalSubvencionUnicaCerti = CDbl(Round(valorSubvencioGastosCerti + valorSubvencionGastosCondiciones, 2))
' ADMINSTJA.TBJAESTTIT   TABLADATOS
'Actualizamos la tabla correspondiente para poder trabajar con su valor
     stsql = "UPDATE  TBJAESTTIT TABLADATOS SET "
    stsql = stsql + " TABLADATOS.TITPRIMAUNICACERTI =" & CvtSql(totalSubvencionUnicaCerti)
    stsql = stsql + " WHERE TABLADATOS.ESTANO='" & sAno & "'"
    stsql = stsql + " AND TABLADATOS.THCOD='" & sTH & "'"
    stsql = stsql + " AND TABLADATOS.OCACOD='" & sOca & "'"
    stsql = stsql + " AND TABLADATOS.CENCOD=" & sCen
    stsql = stsql + " AND TABLADATOS.EXPCOD='" & sExp & "'"
    GBDBAct.Execute stsql, dbFailOnError
    CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023 = 1
    Forms!FRCertificaJA.Refresh
    Exit Function
err_CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023:
    MsgBox "Error al calcular la subvención certificada total. "
    MsgBox stsql
    CalculoPrimaTotalCertificacion2023 = 0
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Gracias y feliz verano